# Backup script not transferring user files?

Tags: python

I have a script I created that copies and zips files from a directory and moves the zipped file into a user inputted directory. My goal was to use it to backup user profiles to a network drive. The problem I am running into is permissions. I was able to get past the NTUSER.dat files by including `asadmin` but the script will not move over documents, desktop etc. I thought elevating the script would do it but no cigar. Here is the portion I'm referring to:

```
    elif object_to_backup_path.is_dir():
    for file in object_to_backup_path.glob('**/*'):
        if file.is_file():
            zip_file.write(
                file.absolute(),
                arcname=str(file.relative_to(object_to_backup_path)),
                compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
            )
```

My question is, what am I missing in order to zip the entire user folder? Currently the result is just appdata and NTUSER.dat. LMK if posting the full script will help. TIA

Comment: User X can backup the files from User X, but he doesn't have permission to touch the files from User Y.  Is that your question?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes and no. I understand file security becomes an issue at that point (owner of the file), but as of right now, it will not transfer ANY personal documents from the user folder. I tried on my own user folder and only appdata and NTUSER got zipped. Yet, it works fine if you define your documents folder and not the user folder.